# PWM control of a 12V DC motor with L9110S driver and Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, pwm, motordriver

My project uses a simple L9110S driver module and it controls 2 motors of the type JGA25-370 (DC 12V, 100RPM). So far I managed to easily control it by setting the pins of the L9110S H-bridge to either high or low.

However, I would like to add PWM control via the Raspberry Pi for this type of motor. Would anyone have any suggestions what would be the best frequency to set for PWM, so that I can safely change the motor speed with the duty cycle, without having the motors jerk and twitch? I have been experimenting and with values higher than 250 Hz, the motors are behaving bad. What would be the "safest" setting?

The motors are currently powered by 8x 1.2V NiMH batteries, so they get around 10 V.

Comment: That might be a driver issue - what does the data sheet say?

Comment: Nothing about that in the datasheet [link](https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf), I only found information that says "A PWM Pulse Width Modulation signal is used to control the speed of a motor and a digital output is used to change its direction."